# How can I fade in a set of images? not a slideshow

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to fade in a set of images similar to how the gallery images are faded in on this site: http://www.archdesignbuilders.com/arch_gallery.php.

The code on the site is pretty horrendous to sift through. I can't seem to figure out how exactly they made this effect happen.

If anyone has any ideas, I would prefer to create it with jquery if at all possible yet would be fine with just a few lines a javascript if thats all I need.

I would be greatly appreciative of any advice.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<img src="image1.gif" class="imagetofadein">
<img src="image2.gif" class="imagetofadein">
<img src="image3.gif" class="imagetofadein">
<img src="image4.gif" class="imagetofadein">
<img src="image5.gif" class="imagetofadein">
<img src="image6.gif" class="imagetofadein">
```

JavaScript with jQuery included:

```
$(".imagetofadein").fadeIn();
```

Comment: This is kinda what I'm going for, yet I would like to have some delay between each image fading in. Something like a timeout that would stagger the time between each instead of all loading at once. Any ideas?